# storing variable length data in variable length table in c

Tags: c, oop, data-structures

i have to store the data like shown in this ->

[image]

i want interface like `set_data(data_id, index, data)` to write data in the table and `get_data(data_id,index)` to read the data from the table

i have to implement this in c code.

need some logical help to write the code.

how it can be done using structures in c.

want to implement something like this.

```
struct INDEX
{
    U8 Len;
    U8 data[];
};

struct DATA_ID
{
    struct INDEX index[];
};

struct DATA_ID data_id[max];
```

`data[]` length varies for each index and
`index[]` length varies for each data_id

Comment: Do you have any idea at all how to write this, or is this a "please give me the code" question?

Comment: Understanding the dynamic memory allocation of C language will help you.

Comment: Just implement as a single struct (`struct collection { size_t group_id, index; double data };`) and then allocate as big a block as you need, e.g. `struct collection *mycollection = malloc (how_many * sizeof *mycollection);`)

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic memory allocation you need to use *malloc*.

One hint for you: Every time you want to initialize a data type of unknown length (size), it's probably a good idea to use *malloc*. The only other solution would be, to use a big enough data type to initialize the unknown data type, but this is just wasting memory and often also wasting performance.

Copied from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   char *str;

   /* Initial memory allocation */
   str = (char *) malloc(15);
   strcpy(str, "tutorialspoint");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   /* Reallocating memory */
   str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);
   strcat(str, ".com");
   printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);

   free(str);
   
   return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
String = tutorialspoint, Address = 355090448
String = tutorialspoint.com, Address = 355090448
```

Comment: The casting of the malloc call serves no purpose.
And you should really add a sizeof(char) into your malloc to avoid problems with different systems.

Comment: This is a tutorial, its purpose is to be simple.

Btw. The purpose of the *malloc* is to allocate enough memory to store the string *str*, which is 15 Bytes long.

Comment: Yes but on certain systems it is possible that a char is not directly 1 byte, so you should add a sizeof in the malloc call.
I also didn't say the malloc had no purpose, but the casting of its call is.